# here, the other / the one / a person which one is right, sticking to 'more of'?

Tags: sentence-usage

Here's a question I'd like to ask someone.

> 1. Are you more of a person spending time alone or **the other** spending time with others.
> 2. Are you more of a person spending time alone or **the one** spending time with others.
> 3. Are you more of a person spending time alone or **a person** spending time with others.

I think 1 could be right because 'more of' implies two thing and one choice and also 'the one' could not be right because 'one' is a specified one not a definite one. and I think 3 is also possible without any worries.
I'd like to know which one is the right one.

Answer (score 2):

None of these sentences are idiomatic. A better phrasing is:

> Are you a person who spends time alone or with others?

Of course, an honest answer to this question will probably be "both", so what you might want to ask instead might be:

> - Do you prefer spending time alone, or with others?
> - Do you spend most of your time alone, or with others?

Answer (score 1):

More is never used before this form: of+article+noun
More and most are the adverbs of many. Eg:  you like many friends. Your friends are more than mine. You like more friends than i do. 
Of+noun can be preceded by the form: "the kind"
eg: Are you the kind of persons who spend most of their time alone or with the others?
However, you can use less number of words.
Eg: Do you prefer spending most of  your time alone or with the others? Instead of "the one" , you use "or" . And instead of "are you the kind of a person who prefers", you use:" do you prefer" So less number of words is  easier to remember.